# object.method notation in Ada

Tags: oop, ada, gnat-gps

does anyone know of a good resource to explain when the `object.method` notation can be used in ada?

for example:

```
person.walk(10);
```

I've been doing a bit of googling and haven't figured it out yet. Does it only apply to tagged records?

I use GPS as my Ada IDE, I quite like being able to go `bla.<type something>` and getting suggested methods to call.

I'm a bit confused also on why the dot notation can't be used for anything where the first parameter matches the type in question.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: See also [_prefixed notation_](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-2-3.html).

Comment: The best resource is [RM 4.1.3(9.2)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-1-3.html), which spells out what possibilities there are for the operation, assuming you understand the terminology (this isn't one of the hardest or one of the easiest sections).  As for why dot notation can't be used on untagged types: that decision was made because of possible ambiguity when the untagged type is an access type, because the same kind of syntax is used for implied ".all".  I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it only applies to tagged record (the vtable is used to find the corresponding method). It can be used for all primitive operations, or for the 'Class operations defined in the same package.
One of the nice benefits of the notation is that you do not need a "with" on the package that defines the type.
We tend to use tagged types more often theses days, just so that we can use the dot notation indeed.

Comment: "The vtable is used to find the corresponding method" isn't always true.  The operation can be a subprogram whose first parameter is a classwide type, in which case it is not a dispatching operation (unless the second or other parameter happens to be of the tagged type) and therefore won't be in the vtable.

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation also applies to task an protected types.